# Regarding questions that belong on Stack Overflow family but also elsewhere

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

After discovering Stack Overflow, it's become to GOTO place for my programming questions. Whether I ask them, or I find that someone else did, my concerns always get answered, and I am very pleased. So for starters, thank you to everyone here.

My current occupation being a programming consultant for a SharePoint deployment, the majority of these are SharePoint related. But not all SP questions belong on any of the SO sites. I can accept that and direct my search elsewhere... which brought me to finding [SharePoint Overflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/). It is exactly a place for me to ask the questions which relate to SP but are off-topic for the trilogy. But then I started to wonder... what about the questions which belong on both? Comparing activity for actual SP questions on Stack Overflow... at least from whenever I am around... it is quite sparse. Whether this is because the majority of SO is kinda weary of SP, or because most of the people who were the main SP advocates on SO have since moved to SPOverflow, who knows. But I began to question... if a question is both SharePoint related and programming related... where should I ask it? SPOverflow had [a thread regarding trying to migrate most of the SP questions from SO over there](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79/should-all-the-sharepoint-question-from-stackoverflow-be-migrated-to-this-site), but there's not much discussion regarding what to do about asking new questions.

I imagine SharePoint isn't the only subject which has its own site but also has questions that actually *do* belong on SO or SU or SF. Thus, this question is for these kind of situations in general. If a question is covered by the SO family and elsewhere, should you ask it in the (most likely) smaller community that is dedicated specifically to your craft? Or should you ask it in the larger place, that may increase its exposure both to those who can answer your question, or those who would ask it themselves? I can see some pros and cons in either way, and it may actually be dependent on the subject. But I suppose I am curious to how the SO community thinks about these edge cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...if a question is both SharePoint related and programming related... where should I ask it?

I'd probably go to the site the specializes in SharePoint *first*, but if it's also programming related I don't see anything wrong with asking it on both.  If you get an answer on one, you should definitely link to it on the other.